# How to extract a specific number of characters before and after a keyword in R?

Tags: r, extract

I have a dataframe (`data`) with a column containing text from reports (`data$Report_Text`). I need to extract 40 characters before and after a keyword (including the keyword) for each row and store as a new column in the dataframe.

So far I have this for the characters before (ideally would like to store the text before + after in one column, but if that isn't possible I can do two columns):

`data$characters <- sub('.*?(\\d{40}) keyword', "", data$Report_Text)`

However when I run this, it gives me all of the text before the keyword, not just 40 characters. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'd try something like `stringr::str_extract(".{40}keyword.{40}")`. Use `{,40}` as the quantifier if you want as many characters as possible if there are less than 40 in the string.

Comment: This worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
data$characters <- gsub("^.*(.{40}keyword.{40}).*$", "\\1", data$Report_Text))
```

posibly changing the `.` before the `{40}` by `\\d` (only digits) or the character type of your preference.

Comment: Thanks, but that is still giving me all of the characters in the text.

Comment: @Jordan I updated the answer. Try with `gsub` instead of `sub`. Note the use of `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of the string. If it yet returns all the text, maybe the text has less than 40 characters on each side, or maybe it does not include the keyword.